# How to fix MSB8029: Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio complains with each compile about with 
`warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build.`

I was checking the projects and changed *Output Directory* and *Intermediate Directory* but I still got the message for each project in my solution.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer - I was missing Environment variables. After adding them and rebooting the problem has gone.

*How to fix it for Windows 7*

1. Be sure that the Intermediate and Output directory do not reside under the Temporary directory! If the problem still persists:
2. Go to Environment Variables (Start->Computer->right click->Properties->Advanced system settings->Tab Advanced->Environment Variables)
3. Add to *User Variables* Variable Name: TEMP, Variable value: %APPDATA%\Local\Temp
4. Add to *User Variables* Variable Name: TMP, Variable value: %APPDATA%\Local\Temp
5. Add to *System Variables* Variable Name: TEMP, Variable value: C:\Windows\Temp
6. Add to *System Variables* Variable Name: TMP, Variable value: C:\Windows\Temp
7. Reboot

Comment: i have as show %APPDATA%\Local\Temp and C:\Windows\Temp but i have same error

Answer (score 1):

This is a truly useless informational warning. I think to direct all intermediate files to a temp folder is an excellent idea. At least when it comes to C++.

The warning is due to a setting in VS2017 `Microsoft.CppBuild.targets`(395):

```
<VCMessage Code="MSB8029" Type="Warning" Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)'!='true' and '$(IgnoreWarnIntDirInTempDetected)' != 'true' and ('$(_IntDirFullpath.StartsWith($(Tmp), true, null))' == 'true' or '$(_IntDirFullpath.StartsWith($(Temp), true, null))' == 'true' or '$(_OutDirFullpath.StartsWith($(Tmp), true, null))' == 'true' or '$(_OutDirFullpath.StartsWith($(Temp), true, null))' == 'true')"/>
```

The implementation is a bit different between VS versions, but the solution is the same. All you need is to disable the trigger by assigning a macro.

1. Open or create your personal properties files `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props` and
   `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props`
2. Add macro `IgnoreWarnIntDirInTempDetected` with value `true`

Done

The solution is valid for VS2013 and VS2015 as well. The personal properties files will be found at:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who run across this issue using VS 2019 (and possibly latter).
(It has nothing to do with TEMP environment variable).
VS 2019 does not support user settings and you should use project settings to disable warnings.
Knowing that MSBuild evaluates properties from environment too, you could define environment variable with same name as MSBuild property. Create following property in session where you would like to disable warning
`set IgnoreWarnIntDirInTempDetected=true`
and start build.